# Decompose time-series signal into different components

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, signal-processing, sensors

I am working with time series data from a sensor that measures particulate matter. I know that there is an ambient/ background concentration (which always exists and can naturally vary due to various conditions) and concentration due to human/other activity (for example vehicular emissions or drilling/mining in the area). I want to take the particulate matter concentration from my sensor and split into two components:

1. Background Concentration
2. Concentration due to human activity/ other activity

I am looking for theory/ any algorithm that can help me solve this problem. I am having trouble to figure where to start. For the purpose of this question I generated data in R.

```
set.seed(100)
true_background <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 5, sd = 0.5) #Assumption here, true background has a mean 5

spike_signal <- rgamma(n = 1000, shape = 2.7, rate = 0.08)

observed_signal <- data.frame(true_background + spike_signal)
```

My desired output would be a data frame that splits the observed_signal into observed_background and observed_spike. Thanks.

Comment: Your data isn't really in the form of a time series. Do you have any existing knowledge of the background noise, or a theoretical model for the signal component? Presumably if you have a time series then there is an element of autocorrelation that your example data doesn't have. Are you able to give a more realistic example, and include any information you have about the distribution of the real noise and real signal in your question?

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron. I did not realize about the autocorrelation part in time-series data. About background noise: I know the mean is about 5 but it varies due to environmental factors and is random (depends on temperature, pressure, humidity) and I do not have a model to describe it. I will look for a more realistic example. Thanks.

Comment: this is a research question, not a matter of programming. the signal processing is secondary. primary is you gaining an understanding of how these things vary, and how you're planning to make them discernible. -- [mre] including data required.